# How to pass arguments to function referenced by variable

Tags: function, powershell, reference, arguments

I have a function 'foo' and a variable '$foo' referencing it.

```
function foo
{
    param($value)
    $value + 5
}

$foo = foo
$foo
```

I can call $foo without args, but how can I pass parameters? This does not work:

```
$foo 5
$foo(5)
```

Actually the goal is to write such code:

```
function bar {
  param($callback)
  $callback 5
}

bar(foo)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is when you do

> $foo = foo

You put the result of the function in the variable $foo, not the function itself !

Try this :

> $foo = get-content Function:\foo

And call it like this

> & $foo 5

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 3):

Use a script block.

```
# f.ps1

$foo = 
{
    param($value)
    $value + 5
}

function bar 
{
  param($callback)
  & $callback 5
}

bar($foo)
```

Running it:

```
> ./f.ps1
10
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Misread the question the first time

What you need to do is use the & operator

```
& $foo 5
```

Comment: Actually you did not misread it, I just updated the question to be more clear :-) Btw, your solution still does not work...

Answer (score 0):

$foo = foo 5